# Multiple return of a function

Tags: python, return, conditional-statements

I have a function with multiple returns:

```py
def doc_type(doc_list):
    if doc_validation(doc_list) < 10:
        print("Document can't be processed")
        return None
    else: 
        check = convert_list_to_string(dni_list)
        score = check.find("ESPAÑA")
        if score != 0:
            name = doc_name(doc_list)
            gender = sex(doc_list)
            return name, gender
        else:
            name = doc_nombre(dni_list)
            first_name, second_name = apellidos(dni_list)
            return name, first_name, second_name
```

I assume that the function should stop if conditions are satisfied the first return, but I still get an error message if the case of first return - `"cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"`

How can I return the function (if the case if 1st return is satisfied) without an error (stop the function)?

Comment: could yo extend your example by how you call `doc_type()` so what your surrounding code is, such that we have a working minimal example, such that everyone can reproduce it https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: `None` is a non-iterable object. It's very unusual to have a function that can return None, and tuple of length 2, and also a tuple of length 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to check the return value on the caller's side before you attempt to unpack.

```py
ret_val = doc_type(doc_list)

if ret_val is None:
   # Do something
elif len(ret_val) == 2:
   name, gender = ret_val
   # Do something
elif len(ret_val) == 3:
   name, first_name, second_name = ret_val
   # Do something
```

In general it is considered bad practice to have a function that can return tuples of different lengths, especially when they are meant to be unpacked. I would recommed you try to return either `None` or a fixed-size tuple (even if some members of the tuple are `None`).

Additionally, I should mention that `namedtuple` objects, or `dataclasses` since python3.7, are better return types than naked tuples.

This would look like...

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class DocType:
   name: str
   first_name: Optional[str]
   second_name: Optional[str]
   gender: Optional[str]


def doc_type(doc_list) -> Optional[DocType]:
   if doc_validation(doc_list) < 10:
      return None
   ...
   return DocType(name, first_name, second_name, gender)
```

Comment: Better yet, raise an exception rather than returning `None`. That way, if the function *does* return, you know that its value can be unpacked.